# Render 'async' function return value in render method (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, render

I'm trying to render a simple return value from an `async` function in my react app however every time I try to my entire app will not render at all. Without calling the function my app renders fine. Also if I console.log my return value (result) in my function it returns the correct value on the console but nothing in the app renders. Any ideas what's going on?

```
class TitleCards extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.totalPortfolio = this.totalPortfolio.bind(this);
        this.getIntradayPrice = this.getIntradayPrice.bind(this);

    }

    async getIntradayPrice(tick) {
        const resp = await fetch(`${IEX.base_url}/stock/${tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`);
        return resp.json();
      }

    async totalPortfolio() {
        const respPromises = this.props.info.map(({ tick }) => this.getIntradayPrice(tick));
        const respArrays = await Promise.all(respPromises);
        console.log(respArrays);
        const result = respArrays.reduce((acc, val, index) => acc + val[0].close * this.props.info[index].amtPurch, 0)
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      }
      
    render(){  
        return(
            <div className="positioning">
                <div className="StockCardTitle">
                    <img src={Folder} className="StockCardTitle-image" /> 
                    {this.totalPortfolio()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TitleCards;
```

Comment: React components and lifecycle are 100% synchronous, especially the `render` method. The `render` method is also considered a pure function, meaning it should have zero side effects, like fetching data. What is `this.portfolio` in the above snippet? Can you provide a more complete code example so we may see what `portfolio` function is and what is calling `getIntradayPrice` and `totalPortfolio`?

Comment: So i just added the complete component code. Props are passed in from another component but they are simple arrays. The main problem is rendering a asynch function value which I don't know how to do. Also I had an error in the original code snippet (portfolio function was meant to be totalPortfolio) it has been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

React components and lifecycle are 100% synchronous, especially the `render` method. The `render` method is also considered a pure function, meaning it should have zero side effects (like fetching data!!).

## Solution

You should refactor your code to fetch data in one or both of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` and save the result to local component state for rendering.

Here's an example refactorization.

```
class TitleCards extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    state = {
      portfolioTotal: '',
    };

    this.totalPortfolio = this.totalPortfolio.bind(this);
    this.getIntradayPrice = this.getIntradayPrice.bind(this);
  }

  async getIntradayPrice(tick) {
    const resp = await fetch(`${IEX.base_url}/stock/${tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`);
    return resp.json();
  }

  async totalPortfolio() {
    const { info } = this.props;
    const respPromises = info.map(({ tick }) => this.getIntradayPrice(tick));
    const respArrays = await Promise.all(respPromises);
    const result = respArrays.reduce((acc, val, index) => acc + val[0].close * info[index].amtPurch, 0)
    return result;
  }

  // When the component mounts, call totalPortfolio
  componentDidMount() {
    this.totalPortfolio()
      .then(portfolioTotal => {
        this.setState({
          portfolioTotal
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // add any required error handling/messaging here
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { portfolioTotal } = this.state;
    return(
      return(
        <div className="positioning">
          <div className="StockCardTitle">
            <img src={Folder} className="StockCardTitle-image" /> 
            {portfolioTotal} // <-- render state value
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```